# Can the lag function in R re-use calculated values in R without looping?

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

Sample Data

```
set.seed(1)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Category = rep(c("Cat1","Cat2","Cat3"),3),
  Value = c(sample(c(1:10),3), rep(NA, 6))
)
```

I'm trying to seed a data frame with the lagged values of data from past years. This is a simplified version of the problem, but in effect, what I need to do is have `lag` re-use the previously calculated lag value. If you run the below code, rows 4-6 calculate as I intend, but rows 7-9 remain `NA` because `lag` looks at the original value, not the new, calculated one. I'd like rows 7-9 to also populate with the values of rows 4-6. I know I could just write a `for` loop to pull the values forward, but wanted to see if there is a more R-like way to accomplish this.

```
df1 %>% group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), lag(Value, 1), Value))


# Groups:   Category [3]
  Category Value
  <fct>    <int>
1 Cat1         9
2 Cat2         4
3 Cat3         7
4 Cat1         9
5 Cat2         4
6 Cat3         7
7 Cat1        NA
8 Cat2        NA
9 Cat3        NA
```

Desired Result

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   Category [3]
  Category Value
  <fct>    <int>
1 Cat1         9
2 Cat2         4
3 Cat3         7
4 Cat1         9
5 Cat2         4
6 Cat3         7
7 Cat1         9
8 Cat2         4
9 Cat3         7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is applicable to your problem, but you could maybe use `fill`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  fill(Value, .direction = "down")

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   Category [3]
  Category Value
  <chr>    <int>
1 Cat1         9
2 Cat2         4
3 Cat3         7
4 Cat1         9
5 Cat2         4
6 Cat3         7
7 Cat1         9
8 Cat2         4
9 Cat3         7
```

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks! I had to adjust my grouping approach slightly to group by month (not included in my example) in addition to the category but this concisely addresses the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can use `nafill` after grouping by 'Category'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Value := nafill(Value, type = "locf"), Category]
df1
#   Category Value
#1:     Cat1     9
#2:     Cat2     4
#3:     Cat3     7
#4:     Cat1     9
#5:     Cat2     4
#6:     Cat3     7
#7:     Cat1     9
#8:     Cat2     4
#9:     Cat3     7
```